# How to customize the sort when a column appears twice with the same value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Current table :

```
Id name    statusId  CreateDate    
--------------------------------------------
1  "Test"  2         2018-09-21 01:40:14.950
1  "Test"  8         2018-09-21 01:40:01.603
2  "Test"  2         2018-09-21 02:29:55.403
1  "Test"  2         2018-09-21 01:36:59.383
3  "Test"  3         2018-09-21 01:40:22.707
4  "Test"  8         2018-09-21 01:10:11.630
1  "Test"  3         2018-09-21 01:40:16.707
1  "Test"  8         2018-09-21 01:40:16.630
2  "Test"  2         2018-09-21 01:20:15.950
2  "Test"  8         2018-09-21 01:30:02.603
1  "Test"  2         2018-09-21 02:19:55.403
3  "Test"  2         2018-09-21 01:56:59.383
```

Want to find:

```
1  "Test"  2         2018-09-21 02:19:55.403
1  "Test"  3         2018-09-21 01:40:16.707
1  "Test"  8         2018-09-21 01:40:16.630
1  "Test"  2         2018-09-21 01:40:14.950
1  "Test"  8         2018-09-21 01:40:01.603
1  "Test"  2         2018-09-21 01:36:59.383
```

How to sort statusId as fixed order(2-3-8-2-8-2) and CreateDate DESC?

I try to use this SQL statement, but it does not return my expected results:

```
select id 
from table
where statusId = 8
   or statusId = 3
   or statusId = 2
order by 
    createDate desc, 
    case 
       when statusId = 3 then 1
       when statusId = 8 then 2
       when statusId = 2 then 3
    end asc
```

Comment: So you want all the records with statusID=3 to come first, then all those with statusID=8, and finally statusID=2.      And then, within each of those groups, sort descending by createDate.

Comment: I think you might just have your sort parameters out of order.  Put the CASE first, and createDate afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish what you want with `row_number()`:

```
select . . .   -- it seems strange to select id because that is always "1"
from table
where statusId in (2, 3, 8)
order by row_number() over (partition by statusId order by createdDate desc),
         (case when statusId = 3 then 1
               when statusId = 8 then 2
               when statusId = 2 then 3
          end) asc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just have your sorts backwards.

The way you have it now, you are sorting by `CreateDate`. The second clause of the `sort by` is there to break any ties. It's saying "If there are multiple rows with the same `CreateDate` value, then sort those by the `case` expression."  Since all your CreateDate values are unique, the second sort clause is ignored. There are no ties to break.

```
create table MyTable ( ID         int, 
                       Name       varchar(10),
                       StatusID   int,
                       CreateDate datetime )

insert into MyTable ( ID, Name, StatusID, CreateDate ) values
( 1, 'Ella',    2, '2018-09-21T01:40:14.950' ),
( 1, 'Spencer', 8, '2018-09-21T01:40:01.603' ),
( 2, 'Daisy',   2, '2018-09-21T02:29:55.403' ),
( 1, 'Chloe',   2, '2018-09-21T01:36:59.383' ),
( 3, 'Ivy',     3, '2018-09-21T01:40:22.707' ),
( 4, 'Alyssia', 8, '2018-09-21T01:10:11.630' ),
( 1, 'Hallie',  3, '2018-09-21T01:40:16.707' ),
( 1, 'Carole',  8, '2018-09-21T01:40:16.630' ),
( 2, 'Blake',   2, '2018-09-21T01:20:15.950' ),
( 2, 'Mary',    8, '2018-09-21T01:30:02.603' ),
( 1, 'Vivian',  2, '2018-09-21T02:19:55.403' ),
( 3, 'Theresa', 2, '2018-09-21T01:56:59.383' )

select ID, Name, StatusID , CreateDate
from MyTable
where StatusID in ( 2, 3, 8 )
order by

  case
    when StatusID = 3 then 1
    when StatusID = 8 then 2
    when StatusID = 2 then 3
  end asc,

  CreateDate desc
```

Comment: Did you find this helpful?

Comment: sorry for delay response, it is not my expected, just want to find fixed order (2-3-8-2-8-2) with statusid, the example table just have one ID match this case, so the result must be        
     `1  "Vivian"   2         2018-09-21 02:19:55.403
      1  "Hallie"   3         2018-09-21 01:40:16.707
      1  "Carole"   8         2018-09-21 01:40:16.630
      1  "Ella"    2         2018-09-21 01:40:14.950
      1  "Spencer"   8         2018-09-21 01:40:01.603
      1  "Chloe"   2         2018-09-21 01:36:59.383`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution as below, it meets my expected.

```
select * from MyTable t1
join MyTable t2
    on t1.ID = t2.ID
join MyTable t3
    on t1.ID = t3.ID
join MyTable t4
    on t1.ID = t4.ID
join MyTable t5
    on t1.ID = t5.ID
where t1.statusID = 3
    and t2.statusID = 8
    and t3.statusID = 2
    and t4.statusID = 8
    and t5.statusID = 2
    and t1.CreateDate > t2.CreateDate
    and t2.CreateDate > t3.CreateDate
    and t3.CreateDate > t4.CreateDate
    and t4.CreateDate > t5.CreateDate
    and DATEDIFF(minute, t2.CreateDate, t1.CreateDate) < 1 
    and DATEDIFF(minute, t3.CreateDate, t2.CreateDate) < 1
    and DATEDIFF(minute, t4.CreateDate, t3.CreateDate) < 1
    and DATEDIFF(minute, t5.CreateDate, t4.CreateDate) < 10
order by t1.ID, t1.CreateDate desc
```